# C++ how to cast return value from sscanf

Tags: c++, casting, scanf, warnings, return-value

today I would like to know if there is a way to cast the return value which I got from sscanf. The idea is that I am currently using the following code:

```
sscanf(reinterpret_cast<char *>(randomString), "%x", &hMonLongExam)
```

where

```
hMonLongExam
```

My question is if there is a possible way to get rid of

```
warning C4477: 'sscanf' : format string '%x' requires an argument of type 'unsigned int *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'HMONITOR *'
```

without using `#pragma ignore` of course.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show the definition of CUSTOMOBJECT? Why do you think shutting up the compiler is the best approach?

Comment: The `scanf` function family are C only. They don't know anything about C++ objects. Why can't you create some kind of setter function which parses the string (using e.g. `std::stoi`) and uses the value some way.

Comment: Sorry I cannot show you the definition of CUSTOMOBJECT since it is confidential, thats why I use pseudocode. And for the std::stoi... I am not sure if I can use it that way, since this sscanf is used within the if statement and I am asking weather the output from sscanf is ==1

Comment: The [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function have validation of the string, which I guess is why you check the result of `sscanf`. And to reiterate my previous point: It's just not possible to use C++ class or structure instances as arguments to any `scanf` family function.

Comment: oh, that's a valid point. I am gonna check it right away. I am gonna let you know soon :)

Comment: With "cannot show you the definition of CUSTOMOBJECT since it is confidential", too much remains unclear.  Post an equivalent [mcve].

Comment: I updated the question. CUSTOMOBJECT is basicky just a HMONITOR

Comment: The compiler is complaining about the type of `&hMonLongExam`, not about the type of the value returned by `sscanf`. `sscanf` returns `int` and gives you some information about what happened in the formatting. The code in the question asks `sscanf` to read a value into an `unsigned int`; the actual field being read has a different type. You might be able to suppress that warning, but that would be treating a symptom and not the actual problem.

Comment: yes this is the point.. my question is if it is able to cast the value to another type... the following piece is just a hypothetical pseudo-code... sscanf(reinterpret_cast<char *>(randomString), "%x", (HMONITOR)&hMonLongExam).. see the casting before hMonLongExam

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char *>(randomString)` is probably wrong. And handles are typically unique per process. Why do you need this handle? What are you going to use it for? Where does the string and its contents come from? Right now this is very much an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).